# Xamarin iOS app crash while horizontal scrolling back and forth

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a controller that host scrollview. ScrollView behave like a pager. Every page is separate UIViewController. While I try to swipe very quickly back and forth the app crashes with following stacktrace

```
Thread 3 Crashed:
1   libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 16
2   App.IOS wrapper_managed_to_native_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr_intptr_0 (<unknown>:1)
3   App.IOS Xamarin_iOS_CoreAnimation_CALayerDelegate_Dispose_bool (CALayerDelegate.cs:47)
4   App.IOS Xamarin_iOS_Foundation_NSObject_Finalize (NSObject2.cs:129)
5   App.IOS mscorlib_wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_virtual_void__this___object_intptr_intptr_intptr + 104
6   App.IOS mono_gc_run_finalize (gc.c:311)
7   App.IOS sgen_gc_invoke_finalizers (sgen-gc.c:2537)
8   App.IOS finalizer_thread (gc.c:885)
9   App.IOS start_wrapper (threads.c:829)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body + 304
```

With following exception message

```
objc_msgSend() selector name: setDelegate:
```

As I understand it problem with GC. Anybody got any ideas why it happening ?

Comment: Could you attach the code how you add the viewcontroller to scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I was using 3rd party UI library with a Chart. On every switch of the screen (on view appear), I was updating a Chart with new Series, but before update had to clear previous Series.

```
Series.Clear();
```

So problem was that Series still was leaving in mono, but in objective-c they were dead and when GC happened it try to send a message to objective-c that have been already released. I will notify a library holding company about this bug.